# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tinymce is not a function

Tags: forms, tinymce

I get this error with an tinymce form

```
$(document).ready(function () { 


if (typeof(base_url) == "undefined") {
    var base_url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/';
}

$("#additional-information").tinymce({
    script_url : 'http://sab-solutions.com/phpformbuilder/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
    document_base_url: base_url,
    relative_urls: false,
    theme: "modern",
    language: 'fr_FR',
    element_format: "html",
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        "autolink autoresize charmap contextmenu link lists paste table"
    ],
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    contextmenu: "link inserttable | cell row column deletetable",
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link",
    schema: "html5"
});

    });
```

The form are in this website

sab-solutions.com/site/emploi.php

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you that there is no `tinymce` property or method on the jQuery object - when you call

`$("#additional-information").tinymce...`

You are trying to access a method or property on the `$("#additional-information")` jQuery object that does not exist.

There is no issue using document ready to init TinyMCE you just can't do what you have in that code.

Instead do something like:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#additional-information',
    .
    .  
    .
});
```

This will get you the same end result (TinyMCE will take over that field).

If you are still stuck I would suggest creating a simple TinyMCE Fiddle that shows what you have so people can see all the code that you are trying to run.

**Note:**  *When you use `$("#additional-information").tinymce...` that would only work with the jQuery version of TinyMCE.  If you are using the regular distribution those calls won't work.  My recommendation would be to use the regular distribution as it does not add the overhead of creating additional jQuery objects to make TinyMCE play within the jQuery environment.*

Comment: the same code work fine in the form script demo:
sab-solutions.com/templates/forms/cv-submission-form.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a reference to the tinyMCE JS library. They have a version hosted on CDN at [//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js](http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js), you can download it manually, or use a package manager like bower.

To refernece an external javascript file use the script tag with a src attribute:

`<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Hello
this script are alredy included

<script src="http://sab-solutions.com/phpformbuilder/plugins/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>

Answer (score -2):

solved!
the problem was that i included twice the jquery js

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11994735)

Comment: @Dheer: Actually it's OP's answer, documenting the fix :)

Comment: @DanCornilescu Understood. I guess I should have typed free form comment rather than use standard. OP should have elaborated more the answer. In the present form it looks more of a comment than answer.