# MathType External Plugin for TinyMCE not working

Tags: plugins, tinymce, external, mathtype

I'm trying to integrate MathType into my TinyMCE editor but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: tinymce.create is not a function
    at 2 (plugin.js:1:163253)
    at __webpack_require__ (plugin.js:1:208570)
    at plugin.js:1:208973
    at plugin.js:1:208997
```

I'm using the external plugin route as described here:

https://docs.wiris.com/mathtype/en/mathtype-integrations/mathtype-web-interface-features/external-integration.html

My code (partial):

```
function create_tinymce(element){
            //alert(element)
            document.getElementById("savePost").style.display = 'block';

            tinymce.init({
                selector: element,
                inline: true,
                //skin: 'jb',
                custom_elements: 'dictTerm',
                extended_valid_elements: 'dictTerm',
                content_css : 'css/stylesheet.css',
                menubar: false,
                toolbar: 'undo redo | table image | alignleft aligncenter bullist numlist | forecolor backcolor link | h2 calculationBox importantBox | tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor code',
                plugins: 'code image lists link preview table',
                external_plugins: { tiny_mce_wiris: 'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/tiny_mce/plugin.js' },
```

I am also loading in jQuery and he tinyMCE plugin before the html loads:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/###APIKEYHIDDEN###/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1//###APIKEYHIDDEN###/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tinymce/tinymce-jquery@2/dist/tinymce-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know what might be going wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the issue, is it possible that there are missing closing tags in your code?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#additional-information',
    .
    .  
    .
}); ----> **this is missing?**
```

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576149/uncaught-typeerror-tinymce-is-not-a-function).

Comment: thank you for your reply!
I checked it, and unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue.

I heavily simplified my code into a Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ilyas415/4xsc517q/2/

Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me. Does it work for you? Could it be a problem with my browser?